# Vue access iteration item inside method from template

Tags: vuejs2

Learning `Vue` and stuck.

I am trying to access `user` in each of the methods to confirm `true/false` values for each `isHuman` and `isPlayerTurn` functions. How do I access the `user` in the loop instance inside each method?

I have the following table row in a template:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h5>Enemies online</h5>
        <span id="no-online-players" class="player-label pull-right">{{ usersCount }}</span>
        <table id="new-game-opponents" class="new-game-opponents">
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" :class="[isPlayerTurn() ? playerTurnClass : '']">
                <td class="player-status text-right">
                    <div v-if="isPlayerTurn">
                        <span :id="['player_turn-' + user.owner_id]" class="stage-label pull-right">{{ progress }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:5px;"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="player-status text-right">
                    <div v-if="isHuman">
                        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:2px;"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['users', 'usersCount'],

        data: function () {
            return {
                playerTurnClass: 'next-player-turn',
                myPlayer: my_player,
                progress: game.progress.status.turn_status.current_stage
            }
        },

        methods: {
            isPlayerTurn: function(user, index) {
                    return this.myPlayer.id === this.users[index]['id'];
            },
            isHuman: function(user, index) {
                return this.users[index]['owner_id'] !== 'ai';
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am trying to access `user` in each of the methods to confirm `true/false` values for each `isHuman` and `isPlayerTurn` functions.

How do I access the `user` in the loop instance inside each method? Or should I be doing this a different way?

Additionally, the `progress` property is not rendered. But one step at a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try

```
<div v-if="isPlayerTurn(user, index)">...</div>
```

and

```
<div v-if="isHuman(user, index)">...</div>
```

I noticed you don't really use `user` in both `isPlayerTurn` and `isHuman` methods, so I suggest leaving `user` out.

And regarding `progress`, I don't know where `game` is from, but I'm guessing the value in `game.progress.status.turn_status.current_stage` is dynamic, so I suggest you first try changing `progress` to a computed property:

```
computed: {
  progress() {
      return game.progress.status.turn_status.current_stage
  }
}
```

Comment: @TheRealPapa fix the method problem first, then let me know when you move on to fix the `progress` problem, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Hi @kevlai22, xie xie! Got it working like this: 
`isPlayerTurn(value) {return value === this.myPlayer.id;},` and in template `:class="[isPlayerTurn(user.id) ? playerTurnClass : '']"`

Comment: Hi @kevlai22, why can I not render `'usersCount`? Thanks

Comment: @TheRealPapa It should work, do you get an `undefined` for `usersCount`?

Comment: Hi @kevlai have a look at this q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771093/vuejs2-keeping-counter-up-to-date

Comment: @TheRealPapa How do you use this component?? Did you write sth like`<component :usersCount="usersCount"/>`??