# Vuejs2 keeping counter up to date

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to get a counter value kept up to date dynamically for a list of users in a chat room using `pusher`. The variable `usersCount` is maintained by the `vue` instance and served in a template. The `vue` debug tool shows it as `undefined` in the code below. I am not passing the variable correctly to the template from the instance.

`chat-player-list` template is called like this:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="sidebar-chat">

    <div class="row">
        <chat-player-list ref="users" :users="users"></chat-player-list>
    </div>

    <hr/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <chat-player-messages ref="messages" :messages="messages"></chat-player-messages>
            <h5>Enemies chit chat</h5>
            <chat-player-form v-on:chatmessagesent="addMessage" :player="{{ Auth::user() }}"></chat-player-form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The players all list and render OK, and additionally the rest of the conditional functions work OK. Just the `usersCounter` not rendering.

My `chat.js` code contains the main `vue` instance:

```
/**
 * Set up Vue components for chat
 */
$(document).ready(function()
{
    Vue.component('chat-player-list', require('../components/chat-player-list.vue'));
    Vue.component('chat-player-messages', require('../components/chat-player-messages.vue'));
    Vue.component('chat-player-form', require('../components/chat-player-form.vue'));

    var chatPlayer = new Vue({
        el: '#sidebar-chat',

        data: function () {
            return {
                game: game,
                messages: [],
                users: [],
                usersCount: 0
            };
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchPlayers();
            this.fetchMessages();

            Echo.join(chat_channel)
                .here((users) => {
                    $.each(users, function(index, value) {
                        $('i#online-' + users[index].id).addClass('faa-ring animated player-online');
                    });
                    this.usersCount = users.length;
                })
                .joining((user) => {
                    $('i#online-' + user.id).addClass('faa-ring animated player-online');
                    this.usersCount = this.usersCount + 1;
                })
                .leaving((user) => {
                    $('i#online-' + user.id).removeClass('faa-ring animated player-online');
                    this.usersCount = this.usersCount - 1;
                })
                .listen('ChatMessageSent', (e) => {
                    this.messages.unshift({
                        message: e.message.message,
                        player: e.player
                    });
                });
        },

        methods: {
            fetchPlayers() {
                this.users = game.progress.status.players_status;
            },

            fetchMessages() {
                axios.get(chat_get_route)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.messages = response.data;
                    });
            },

            addMessage(message) {
                this.messages.unshift(message);

                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.messages.scrollToTop();
                });

                axios.post(chat_send_route, message)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In my template `chat-player-list.vue` I have:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h5>Enemies online</h5>
        <span id="no-online-players" class="player-label pull-right">{{ usersCount }}</span>

        <hr/>

        <table id="new-game-opponents" class="new-game-opponents">
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" :class="[isPlayerTurn(user.owner_id) ? playerTurnClass : '']">
                <td class="player_number">
                    <div :class="['opponent player-' + index++]" v-once>{{ index++ }}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="player-avatar">
                    <img :id="['player_avatar-' + user.owner_id]" class="setup_player_avatar" :src="[user.avatar]" v-once/>
                </td>
                <td class="player-name">
                    <div :id="['player_nickname-' + user.owner_id]" v-once>
                        {{ user.nickname }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <i :class="[isThisPlayer(user.owner_id) ? 'fa fa-user-circle-o' : 'hidden']" aria-hidden="true" style="color:DarkOrange;"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="player-status text-right">
                    <div v-if="isPlayerTurn(user.owner_id)">
                        <span :id="['player_turn-' + user.owner_id]" class="stage-label pull-right">{{ progress }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:5px;"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="player-status text-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-comments" :id="['online-' + user.owner_id]" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="player-status text-right">
                    <div v-if="isHuman(user.owner_id)">
                        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:2px;"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['users', 'usersCount'],

        data: function () {
            return {
                playerTurnClass: 'next-player-turn',
                nextPlayerId: game.progress.next_player_id,
                progress: game.progress.status.turn_status.current_stage,
                myPlayerId: my_player.id
            }
        },

        methods: {
            isPlayerTurn(thisUserId) {
                return thisUserId == this.nextPlayerId;
            },
            isThisPlayer(thisUserId) {
                return thisUserId == this.myPlayerId;
            },
            isHuman(thisUserOwnerId) {
                return thisUserOwnerId != 'ai';
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

What did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you are using `chat-player-list` in root instance element and how are you passing the prop

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna Hi, I have added as you asked. Let me know if I misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: you are not passing the `usersCount prop

Comment: Hi @Vamsi Krishna I am 3 days `vue` old. Where I am not passing it? I thought I was by declaring it in `data` in main `vue` instance and as a `prop` in the template. A `console.log()` of users shows the content so it is passing through. Did I just get lucky with `users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data won't be passed to child component automatically, you need manually declare it as [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

> Every component instance has its own isolated scope. This means you cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data in a child component’s template. Data can be passed down to child components using props.

*Updated*

You should bind `usersCount` like `<chat-player-list ref="users" :users="users" :users-count="usersCount"></chat-player-list>`

`:a="b"` is a shorthand syntax of v-bind. It means passing current instance's
data `b` to the child component as a prop named `a`. Without this, the child component cannot receive it even though `prop:['a']` exists.
So just add `:users-count="usersCount"`.

As Vamsi mentioned, usersCount should be passed as `users-count`, See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Comment: Hi @choasia but I am passing it in a prop, no? `users` array ispassing through OK. Also the changes to `usersCount` happen in the `vue` instance and not in the template

Comment: @TheRealPapa would you provide your parent's template and child component's js code?

Comment: Hi @choasia I updated the question with all the code requested. `usersCount` gets updated in `chat-players.js` (main `vue` instance) and it is displayed in `chat-player-list.vue` template

Comment: @TheRealPapa Hi, thanks. But I'm still wondering how does `#sidebar-chat` look like.

Comment: @TheRealPapa Saw that. I updated my answer. You just forgot to bind usersCount, right?

Comment: Hi @choasia I just added the binding but it stills does not show the value in the rendered view.

Comment: @TheRealPapa check my update. I added `:usersCount="usersCount"`. Have a look at this section: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props

Comment: @choasia its better you use kebab-case in template and camelCase in javascript as html is case-insensitive and be sure you do not run into any bugs. So pass the prop as `:users-count="usersCount"`....+1...:)

Comment: You both ROCK! Adding the binding and changing the camel case got it working!